# ClamAV detected CVE-2014-8449 in some PDFs. How do I know if it's a real problem?

Tags: virus, pdf

We run clamav on all our user-uploaded files. It's currently giving this message for several PDFs:

`<filename...>: Pdf.Exploit.CVE_2014_8449 FOUND`

Looking at the CVE, it's for a integer overflow in Acrobat. So what does it mean that a PDF matches a signature definition for it? Has ClamAV detect actual code that would run as a result of the overflow, or could this be a false positive? How would I tell?

If there is indeed malicious code in these PDFs, we'd like to stop serving them and inform the users. But it would be nice to know if these are just a bunch of false positives.

Comment: Looks like https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/78634/detected-virus-in-pdf-should-i-be-worried-cve-2014-8449 attracted more attention. One or the other will have to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Huh. I wonder why that one got so many more responses.

Comment: Randomness that got the other one over the Hot Questions threshold, I presume.

Answer (score 2):

If the files are not sensitive from a content point of view you can upload them to a checker such as [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/)

If this also gives you a positive result it's likely an infection.